# Status 0 when deploying Discord bot to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

So i was trying to host a small discord bot I made in python, it runs fine locally but when i deploy to heroku this error comes.

```
2020-09-28T14:30:15.338753+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`

2020-09-28T14:30:15.949195+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-09-28T14:30:19.481846+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-28T14:30:19.521977+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-09-28T14:30:19.524297+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-28T14:30:23.686504+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2020-09-28T14:30:24.559578+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-09-28T14:30:29.094293+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-09-28T14:30:29.139007+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/ghosts-power/Discord_bot
i think its an issue with the procfile i do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `procfile`. Code 0 means that your code executed without any errors.

The problem is that there's nothing being executed in your `bot.py` file.
You need to call:

```
bot.run(token)
```

at the end of the file.

You can also use:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected do Discord')
```

This will tell you when the bot connects to the server.